# Eclipse Luna + Jboss Tools = Heap space error while editing HTML or JS

Tags: eclipse, jboss-tools

I need to use hibernate in my projects and I need a better code completion when editing HTML file or JSF file, so I installed Jboss Tools from the Eclipse Marketplace.
I use this combo since 2010 , but since last update I am experiencing some random "out of memory error" in eclipse.
I've edited the config file to enhance the heap and the perm space, but even with more then 3gb dedicated, the error still persist.

Is anyone experiencing this?
Has anyone found a solution?

I think there are a lot of people with the same issue, because even after a fresh installation of both ide and plug-in the issue persists.

On google I can't find anything useful and I don't think the solution is not incrementing the heap much more, because the memory inspector shows an usage of less then 300MB and my heap is 3GB at the moment. When the error occurs the heap space is blown up instantly from 300MB to 3GB and after a bunch of second the ide shows the error popup. After the error, the heap became less than 300MB.

NOTE: The issue is manifesting with jdk 1.7, 1.8 (all the updates of this and last year) and on a Windows PC (it happens with both Windows 7 and Windows 8/8.1 )

Comment: what version of JBoss Tools are you using ?

Comment: I'm using Jboss Tools 4.4 for Eclipse Luna.

Comment: if you can provide us with some steps or projects to reproduce the issue with we can help track it down. best place to report such bugs is at https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBIDE.

Comment: I'm not completely sure that the bug is coming from Jboss Tools, it could be an Eclipse bug that comes out when you add Jboss Tools. That's why I didn't open a Jira.

I'll create a little project with the issue for your jira

Comment: You still can open issue in JBoss Tools JIRA. Please provide stacktrace so we can find out what is the problem and report it upstream in eclipse bugzilla.

Answer (score 0):

I did some intense investigation on the issue. I found that wasn't causal! The issue would ALWAYS happen while editing an HTML file whith some inline JS.

So what's the problem? 
The problem is the JS validator. 
Disabling the JS validator on compile solve the issue (it's not a true solution but it's the only way I found at the moment).

I think that HTML validator and JS validator interfere each other causing some loop leading to an OutOfMemoryException on Eclipse.

Comment: Would be good to see stacktrace, we are extremely interested in making Eclipse JSDT tools better :)